# Can I use `for all` in a configuration to bind generated instances?

Tags: vhdl

My VHDL architecture instantiates a bunch library cells, some of them within `generate` blocks, e.g.

```
a_inst: foo_cell
  port map ( ... );

b_gen: for i in 1 to 3 generate
  b_inst_i : foo_cell
    port map ( ... );
end generate b_gen;
```

In the configuration, I want to bind these instances to specific configurations in the library.  I would like to use `for all` as in

```
for all : foo_cell
  use configuration foo_lib.foo_cell_cfg;
end for;
```

One might expect this to cover also the `generate` blocks, but no, the most succinct possibility I have found for those is

```
for b_gen
  for all : foo_cell
    use configuration foo_lib.foo_cell_cfg;
  end for;
end for;
```

This needs to be repeated for every `generate`.

Is there a more concise way to achieve the same result?

**EDIT:** Here is a compilable example (with the "library cell" in `work` instead of a separate library for simplicity)

```
entity foo_cell is
end foo_cell;

architecture RTL of foo_cell is
begin
end RTL;

configuration foo_cell_cfg of foo_cell is
  for RTL
  end for;
end foo_cell_cfg;

entity MWE is
end MWE;

architecture RTL of MWE is
  component foo_cell
  end component;
begin
  a_inst: foo_cell;
  b_inst: for i in 1 to 3 generate
    b_i: foo_cell;
  end generate;
end RTL;

configuration MWE_RTL_cfg of MWE is
  for RTL
    for all : foo_cell
      use configuration work.foo_cell_cfg;
    end for;

    for b_inst
      for all : foo_cell
        use configuration work.foo_cell_cfg;
      end for;
    end for;
end for;
end MWE_RTL_cfg;
```

I put all of this in a single file `mwe.vhd` and checked it with `irun -elaborate mwe.vhd -top mwe_rtl_cfg`

Comment: Can you give us a minimal compete verifiable example?

Comment: ... And please specifically explain why (and how) you want to use configurations and not use default assignment, for example

Comment: 2. First, I am working on an existing code generator, and want to preserve its behavior (more or less -- so far it produced a separate `use configuration` for *every* instance, which I hoped to compress a bit using `for all`).  Second, at my organization the convention is to use always configurations (the coding guideline says, essentially, mandatory if there are multiple architectures, recommended if only one).

Practically speaking, I think default assignment would be OK in this case since there is only one architecture for each of the library cells.

Comment: I'll add that (1) this is VHDL 87, in case this makes a difference.  (2) I am quite new to VHDL (and HDLs in general), so especially with regards to your question "why and how do I want to use configurations", I am not sure I completely understand the issue myself.

Comment: For starters, a problem is that `b_inst_i` -being inside of a generate statement- is not visible in the architecture where `a_inst` is visible. I'm now trying to figure out what the possibilities of configuration specifications are, but I find them limited. Often what you are trying to achieve can be solved another way. For instance replacing `b_inst_i : foo_cell` with `b_inst_i : entity foo_lib.foo_cell(foo_lib.foo_cell_cfg)`. But I need to understand how you are using the configuration spec. in your code.

Comment: Again: the problem is that `b_i` is not visible from the scope of `RTL`. That's why you need two statements.